# Invalid field name in matlab

Tags: matlab, struct, field

I have a function that takes in the personalia of a person

```
function person = prompt_person ()
name = input ( ' Whats your name ? ' , 's' ) ;
day = input ( ' What day of the month were you born ? ') ;
month = input (' What month were you born ? ') ;
year = input ( ' What year were you born? ') ;
phone = input ( ' Whats your telephone number ? ') ;
date_of_birth = struct ('day', day, 'month', month, 'year', year) ;
person = struct ( 'name' , name, 'date_of_birth' , date_of_birth , 'phone' , phone ) ;
end
```

But I keep getting the error message "Invalid field name "name" ", "Error message in prompt_person (line 8) And I have no idea whats wrong because I've tried creating a simpler little test function:

```
function [out] = tes( )
word=input('Insert word here ','s');
num=input('Insert number here ');
out= struct('Number1', word, 'Number2', num);
end
```

And it works just fine, even though it seems to be the exact same code which gets me in toruble in the first function. Any ideas what's going on here?

Comment: Try to use `personName` as variable name.

Comment: Can't reproduce this over here...What MATLAB version are you using?

Comment: Im using Matlab r2013a

Answer (score 0):

I tried changing the variable name to personName as suggested and I accidentaly found out whats wrong:
Turn out I needed to use a variable name with no space between the '' and the text.

E.g. 'PersonName' instead of ' PersonName '.

Answer (score 0):

You might consider using [`strtrim`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/strtrim.html) to strip leading and trailing whitespeace from a string.  For example:

```
>> name = ' John Doe   ';
>> name = strtrim(name)
name =
John Doe
```

If you need to remove all spaces, try `strrep(name,' ','')`.

```
>> name = strrep(name,' ','')
name =
JohnDoe
```